# Manwha which the female lead travels to back to historical Korea (maybe to the Goryeo or Joseon period)

Tags: story-identification, time-travel, manga

Does someone know the title of a tragically-themed manhwa (South Korean comic) in which the female lead character travels from the modern era to the past in order to save her father?  The father dies despite her efforts, and the female lead character opts to stay in the past.

The lead male character in the story is a prince from this past era, who somehow  accidentally travels to the modern era where he meets the female lead character at some point, falling in love with her.  Both the female and male leads have black hair and eyes

The two meet again in the past era, where the female character is now working as a servant (possibly a maid).  She becomes pregnant at some point, but is isolated and goes blind.  She ends up losing custody of her child as well.

There was also a secondary male character in the story who was always present in the female lead character's company.

Comment: FL, ML, FLFMFLFML. Please spell out what you mean, there's no tax on writing full words.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  When and where did you read this?